# TYPO3 - Adding extbase viewhelper via javascript to partial

Tags: datatables, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I have a partial ... and if I add a link via link.action ... the link is working perfectly fine:

MyPartial.html:

```
<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" pluginName="abc" controller="Abc" extensionName="abc" arguments="{record:1}">ActionLink</f:link.action>
```

But if I want to add the link.page viewhelper via Javascript to the partial ...

MyPartial.html

```
  <table id="lei_all" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column01</th>
        <th>Column02</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

JS:

```
var table_all = $('#table_all').DataTable( {
        dom: "Blrtip",  
        ajax: {
              url: "/source.php",
              type: "POST"
        },
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true,
        columns: [
            { data: "column_01", 
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return '<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" pluginName="abc" controller="Abc" extensionName="abc" arguments="{record:1}">'+data+'</f:link.action>';
                } },

            { data: "column_02" }                          
        ],
        ...
    } );
```

I'm getting the raw view helper like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id=row_1 class="odd" role="row">
        <td tabindex="0"><f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" pluginName="abc" controller="Abc" extensionName="abc" arguments="{record:1}">ActionLink</f:link.action></td>     
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I add the viewhelper in the above case?

Comment: It seems to me that there is missing a proper closing tag.

Comment: That's a copy paste mistake ... its properly closing as you can see now

Answer (score 1):

ViewHelpers simply do not work that way. What you are trying is equivalent to calling a PHP function in JavaScript to build a string. The expected result of this is that you will see the Fluid tag output, exactly as you describe.

The only way is to construct your links in PHP and (somehow) transfer them to the JavaScript. Valid ways of doing that includes:

- Using `data-something` properties to carry URLs from HTML to JS
- Using an XHR request to create links for a certain purpose
- Generating a list of all links indexed by whichever identifier it has in the table, as a JSON or other file in for example `typo3temp`, then reading this list and using the appropriate link when rendering your table in JS.

Depending on what you need, pick one and implement it so you do not have Fluid code in your JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My problem is the API for the table is not coming from TYPO3 ... it's external. But I do want to link on the detail profile of a record. But if it is a new record where there has no realurl link yet been created ... the detail record is not available. Therefore I wanted to use the link via the link.action 'show' (which creates the realurl link if not available). Do you have any recommendation how I could accomplish this?

Comment: You would have to consult the documentation for the remote API you're using, then consider how you can connect that with one of the above methods of generating URLs. I've modified the answer to include a third option for generating URLs.